# Is there any way to export jconsole monitoring result?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

Jconsole is great in monitoring java application through JMX.

Once connected and running, it could display the whole Memory/Heap/CPU/Thread history of the monitored program.

I just wondering if there is any way to export the result,

and then can load to display the result again?

Instead of just making a screen shot. Is there any 3rd party plugin can do this?

Have googled but without any luck.

Comment: If on Java 6, have you considered using [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) instead? It has the ability to to save and view a snapshot of your application profile (CPU, heap, classes & threads), and more...

Comment: Yes, I am using both visualvm and jconsole, and there is one problem in visualvm that the charts can only display a quite short period of time. I have checked visualvm again, and found that we can change the charts display time by _Option -> General -> Charts Cache_. Thanks @AlistairIsrael, visualvm is the tool I want.

Answer (score 2):

In summary graph you can export sub areas by right clicking and selecting 'export' to csv.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this programatically? As in I am monitoring an application overnight. But jConsole keeps getting disconnected for some reason so I would like to keep exporting data and appending at a certain frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install and configure JMXTRANS (http://www.jmxtrans.org/) which enables JVM remote monitoring so as to send time series data to a centralized monitoring tool such as GRAPHITE (http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).